# Compare 2 Files if it falls between a range of numbers

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I have 2 files,

File 1:

```
4
7
2
```

File 2:

```
1 5 Alpha
6 10 Bravo
11 15 Charlie
16 21 Delta
22 30 Echo
```

I want to compare every entry in file 1 if it lies between col 1 and col 2 of file 2 (should be checked for entire file 2) and if it matches, it should print
 respective col 1 of file 1 and column 3 of file 2.

I tried using,`paste file1 file2 | awk '$1>$2+0 && $1<$3+0 {print $1,$4}'`

But doesn't appears to be working.

When running,`paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1}'`

It outputs as,

```
4
7
2
16
22
```

`paste` command combines both file and couldn't differentiate files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try following `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$1] = $1+0; next; } { for (i in x) { if (x[i] > $1+0 && x[i] < $2+0) { print x[i], $3; } } }' file1 file2
```

Result should be:

```
4 Alpha
2 Alpha
7 Bravo
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, perl:

```
perl -MPath::Class -lne '
    BEGIN {@codes = map {[split]} file("file2")->slurp; $, = " "}
    $val = $_;
    ($code) = grep {$_->[0] <= $val && $val <= $_->[1]} @codes;
    print $val, $code->[2];
' file1
```