# Compare 2 Files with different rows if it falls between a range of numbers

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have two files with different rows. File 1 has 860 rows, File 2  has 650000 rows.

file 1

```
chr  start    End    CM
1     0       2000   p3.5
1     2400    8000   p5.3
2     9500    20000  q2.4
3     0       3000   p7.6
4     60800  89000   p77.1 
8     12000    36000  q4.5
8     55000    78000  p22.4
```

File 2

```
chr  pos
1     1500
2     10500
4     70000
8     13000
```

I want to compare every entry in file 2 if it lies between col 2 and col 3 of file 1 (also should be checked for col 1 (chr in two file)) and if it matches, it should print respective col 1 and col 2 of file 2 and column 4 of file 1.

Desired output:

```
chr  pos     CM 
1     1500    p3.5
2     10500   q2.4
4     70000  p77.1
8     13000   q4.5
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your question to include information on what you already tried (and where you ran into problems), and what tools you have available? That way, contributors can point you in the right direction without risking to propose a solution that you already know doesn't work.

Comment: thanks. I do it in linux and check this topic (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212100/compare-2-files-if-it-falls-between-a-range-of-numbers) for my problem but didnt work for me because  i need to check first col 1 in both file and then have desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seems to be to sort them and then just parse the sorted list

```
cat file1 file2 | 
     sort -k1,1n -k2,2n | 
     awk 'NF==4{c=$1; lo=$2; hi=$3; cm=$4} 
          NF==2 && c==$1 && lo<=$2 && hi>=$3{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, cm}'
```

The `cat` and `sort` produces a combined list in numeric `chr` and `pos` order

```
chr  pos
chr  start    End    CM
1     0       2000   p3.5
1     1500
1     2400    8000   p5.3
2     9500    20000  q2.4
2     10500
3     0       3000   p7.6
4     60800  89000   p77.1 
4     70000
8     12000    36000  q4.5
8     13000
8     55000    78000  p22.4
```

And the just `awk` through the file once picking up new values of `chr`, `lo`, `hi` and `cm` whenever you hit a line with `NF==4` and test only those lines with `NF==2` for your criteria

```
1       1500    p3.5
2       10500   q2.4
4       70000   p77.1
8       13000   q4.5
```

and with a 650,000 line test file

```
real    0m1.511s
user    0m1.249s
sys     0m0.477s
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. but i still have a problem.when we cat and sort for col1 and col2.  Col3 did not  sort and the results are wrong.

Comment: What is the delimiter in the files? Tab or space?

Comment: the delimiter is tab

Comment: If you do the `cat` and `sort` and forget the `awk`do you get a sensible output as per the second code block? i.e. the 1's grouped together and the sub-sort on `pos`/`start` in ascending order?

Comment: when i only do the cat and sort ,everything is ok. but when i used criteria the results wrong.especially for the line for example line1 ( 0-1500) line 2 (1500-5000) . because the end and start of line is the same ,the results wrong.